# Not able to initialize firebase app using the env variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am working on a **next js** project. I want to use `firestore` in my project. So as the process I am initializing firebase app and firestore in one of my file and using them in another service file. But If I use `env` variable to initialize my firebase app, then it's not working.

Here is my project file structure:
[image]

On `firebase/firebaseClient.js`, I am initializing my firebase app. If I use the value directly then it's working. If I use `env` variable then It's not working.

`firebase/firebaseClient.js`:

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// This not working. Value in the env file is the same
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_MESSAGIN_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// This is working
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "MY_AUTHDOMAIN",
  projectId: "MY_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "MY_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "MY_MESSAGIN_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "MY_APP_ID",
  measurementId: "MY_MEASUREMENT_ID",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

And then in `service/appContent.js` I am fetching data using this code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebaseClient";

export const getAppContent = async () => {
  const contentQuery = collection(db, "/shop/app-design/content");
  const contentData = await getDocs(contentQuery);
  const data = contentData.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  return data;
};
```

When using `env` variable to initialize firebase app, I am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: You have to prefix your environment variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to [expose it to the browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

Comment: Thank you sir it worked. Can you please write this as an answer so I can accept the solution and it will help other if anyone have this problem in future.